# Importing Mozilla's CACerts to JRE

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I recently grabbed a copy of Mozilla's list of CA certs and I'm attempting to import to a new JRE I've downloaded.

List in question (in pem) can be found here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

I have tried various ways of doing it, the most simple being simply attempting to import the .pem directly using the keytool, but I've been unsuccessful in getting it to work.

For some reason upon attempting to do so, only one certificate is added list contains 140 and the jre about 93.

Can anyone please guide my on getting this to work?

Comment: Can you include the commands you are running?

Comment: May help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store